# Почему возникает ошибка Error inflating class com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch? Уже всё пробовал, не помогает

Tags: android, исключения, material-ui, android-switch

(полный текст ошибки внизу).

Если я добавляю `MaterialSwitch` в файл разметки для какой-либо Активности, то всё ок.
Но, если я его добавлю в разметку для item'а RecyclerView, то происходит вышеназванная ошибка при открытии активности.

Все решения, которые я находил, были связаны с наследованием моей темы от темы типа `Material.Components`, ещё каких-то Material-тем, от кучи всяких пробовал наследовать, и ничего не работает. В чём ещё может быть причина?

item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="100"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        android:maxWidth="180dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="-"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/generalText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectedOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        android:maxWidth="130dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="dddfnfhfhddhssiuDFEFEDWUSQWJYQDGFSWQ"
        android:textSize="@dimen/generalText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
        android:id="@+id/enableOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AlarmOptionItem.java:

```
package thematedev.clock;

public class AlarmOptionItem {

    private String name, selectedOption;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private int id;

    public AlarmOptionItem (int id, String name, String selectedOption) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.selectedOption = selectedOption;

    }

    public AlarmOptionItem (int id, String name, boolean isEnabled) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;

    }


    public void setSelectedOption(String selectedOption) {
        this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    }

    public String getSelectedOption() {
        return selectedOption;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

И адаптер:

```
package thematedev.clock;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import thematedev.clock.AlarmOptionItem;
import thematedev.clock.R;

public class AlarmOptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmOptionAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    interface OnClickListener{
        void onClick(AlarmOptionItem item, int position);
    }


    private final OnClickListener onClickListener;

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static AlarmOptionItem item;
    private final List<AlarmOptionItem> items;

    AlarmOptionAdapter(Context context, List<AlarmOptionItem> items, OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_option_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        item = items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        holder.name.setText(item.getName());

        //Выбрать, что показать: текствью с выбранной опцией или свич
        if (item.getSelectedOption() != null) {
            holder.selectedOption.setText(item.getSelectedOption());
        } else {
            holder.selectedOption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.switcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.switcher.setChecked(item.isEnabled());
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onClickListener.onClick(item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView name, selectedOption;
        final MaterialSwitch switcher;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            switcher = view.findViewById(R.id.enableOption);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            selectedOption = view.findViewById(R.id.selectedOption);
        }
    }
}
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at thematedev.clock.AlarmOptionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AlarmOptionAdapter.java:44)
    at thematedev.clock.AlarmOptionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AlarmOptionAdapter.java:23)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
2023-05-01 21:06:41.782  2767-2767  AndroidRuntime          thematedev.clock                     E
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:847)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2951)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1750)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2038)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1633)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7943)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:212)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:147)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:114)
    at com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch.<init>(MaterialSwitch.java:89)
    at com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch.<init>(MaterialSwitch.java:72)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: ```Caused by: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).```, тему приложения поменяйте на AppCompat или MaterialComponents

Comment: Я добавил к свичу строчку ```android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"```, и теперь в логкате другая ошибка: ```Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040109 a=-1}```

Comment: Если в разметке активности работает, то и в разметке элемента должно. Вы в адаптер какой контекст передаёте?

Comment: Тупо методом ```getApplicationContext()```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Отправляю адаптеру контекст как this, и всё отлично